# Post, split props ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

this is the part of the code that works

here I recovered 2 data "title" and "quantity" here it works very well

```
postbackend = () => {
    const newItems = this.props.items.map((item) => {
        const { title, quantity, } = item;
        return {
            title,
            quantity,
        };
    });

    const config = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    body: JSON.stringify({ ...this.state, items: newItems,
};

const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";
fetch(url, config)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
      if (res.error) {
          alert(res.error); 
          this.props.history.replace("/OrderSummaryPaymentFalseScreen");  // Your Error Page
      } else {
          alert(`film ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
          this.props.history.push("/OderSummaryScreen"); // Your Success Page
      }
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e); 
    this.props.history.replace("/OrderSummaryPaymentFalseScreen");  // Your Error Page
}).finally(() => this.setState({
    redirect: true
}));
```

so i tried this ,and I would like to separate "title" and "quantity".

example like this

```
const newItems = this.props.items.map((item) => {
  const { title } = item;
  return {
    title,
  };
});
const newQuantity = this.props.items.map((item) => {
  const { quantity } = item;
  return {
    quantity,
  };
});

const config = {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
},

 body: JSON.stringify({ ...this.state, items: newItems, quantityforproduct: newQuantity,
};
```

but it doesn't work 
Do you have an idea of how to fix this? Neff

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean?

Comment: @Ramin eghbalian 
that I receive an object in this format , on my bdd                           
         "quantityforproduct": "[object Object]"